# Como converter UTF String em ANSI e Criar arquivo de texto em ANSI em um SSD?

Tags: java, android, codificação-de-caracteres, sistema-de-arquivos

Escrevi um aplicativo em Android usando Java, para que os usuários respondam perguntas, que depois são salvas em um arquivo.
O problema é que este arquivo é salvo em `UTF8`.
O usuário final vai abrir este arquivo no `IBM SPSS` que é um aplicativo para Windows e só lê arquivos em `ANSI` (Windows-1252).

**Como eu crio arquivos em `ANSI` para salvar no cartão de memória em meu aplicativo Java-Android?**

Para converter Strings em `ANSI` eu devo usar:

```
String unicode = new String(asciiBytes, "windows-1252");
```

**Isto está correto?**

Meu código antigo para salvar o arquivo é:

```
File interviewFile = new File(placeOfSDD, fileName);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(interviewFile, true);
writer.append(textBody);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

"textBody" é a String a converter para `ANSI`, e "interviewFile" é o arquivo a ser salvo como `ANSI` também.

**Já para ler um arquivo em `ANSI` e convertê-lo em String com `UTF8`, como faço?**

Comment: Note-se que a conversão de UTF8->ANSI tem perda de informação. Há caracteres representáveis em UTF8 que não o são em ANSI. Já a conversão ANSI->UTF8 é segura.

Answer (score 2):

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream(file, true), "windows-1252"
                                );
writer.append(textBody);
writer.close();
```